# Searching content stored in CEWP? Moss2007

Tags: search

Is there a way to configure the search feature to search content stored in CEWP's? My search page always returns "no result" for terms referencing content stored in them.

Comment: Content stored within a CEWP forms part of the page that contains the CEWP. So, if the page is inclued in your Scope (Content Source), it should return all content thereof.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Site Settings > Search Visibility.
Under *Indexing ASPX Page Content*, Select *Always index all ASPX pages on this site*